# Jackson mapping fails for generics passed as parameter

Tags: java, rest, generics, jackson

I have a common api to get different entity from rest API. Below is a method for getting list of entities (Groovy).

```
class CommonRestApi<T>{

CommonRestApi(){        
}
....
List<T> getEntities(Class<T> clazz) {
    ClientResponse response = some_rest_get //works fine
    T[] entities
    if (response.status == 200) {
        try{
            GenericType<ResponseWrapper<T[]>> type = new GenericType<ResponseWrapper<T[]>>(){} //here is error

            entities = response.getEntity(type).getData()
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.debug e.getMessage()
        }
    }
    else {
        log.debug("Status Code: " + response.status)
    }
    return Arrays.asList(entities)
}
}
```

ResponseWrapper class (Java):

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {

private T data;

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

And calling the method with:

```
 commonRestApi.getEntities(MyDomain.class)
```

Here the REST api returns data successfully but the mapping to pojo does not work. The error message is just: null. Can anybody tell me if it is possible at all. If yes please give me some guidance. 
Note: The common API class is in groovy

Comment: You're trying to use a [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) with `new GenericType<ResponseWrapper<T[]>>(){}`, but that can only work with a concrete generic type argument. Where is `T` declared?

Comment: I have added class definition. Please check now.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that you can't instantiate something with generics

```
new GenericType<ResponseWrapper<T[]>>(){}
```

fails for the same reason that

```
new T[10];
```

would fail. The type `T` is completely erased by the compiler, and does not exist at runtime.

Comment: -1 The difference is that instantiating a `GenericType` doesn't involve array creation, which `new T[10]` does.